# how to check-in a file so as it appears on multiple projects on github

Tags: github

I have a single file that is required in multiple projects. All projects are on GitHub. Now this file is checked into project A but is required that project B and project D also should get updated when this file is updated
How do I make sure that all projects are updated with one check-in

Answer (score 0):

Every project has its master branch once any file change done it will push into that master branch later we need to take update to appropriate branches.

Whatever the file change that you have made for project A commit the changes into your main master branch .later from master branch take get updates...

1.git checkout project A
Done the file change
Git commit
git pull
It will get latest updates here

2.git checkout project B
git pull
Here it will show you the latest updates of files. 
Open shell promptselect the particular file manually to commit 
Done

3.git checkout project D
Same like above

So that if you do like above only that particular file will get updated for all your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Does my answer helpful ? Try once.